# Adding user defined keywords or Test Attribute

Tags: pytest

I would like to add custom attributes (or Keywords) to a test which I can access during `pytest_runtest_logreport`.

What I have been doing currently is to set a marker like this
`@pytest.mark.TESTID(98157)` for tests and then use this in `pytest_runtest_logreport` as `report.keywords['TESTID']` which returns a tuple of length 1 having value 98157. So far so good. 
But when I tried to add another marker with defect ID like this `@pytest.mark.JIRA("MyJIRA-124")` this `report.keywords['JIRA']` this gives me integer 1.

So my question is can we not create parameterized marker with `string` parameters

**AND**

If that is the could be the probable workaround for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately "report" will not have this vaules in default implmentation as it's only a dict with 1 as values for each key ([source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/82fb63ca2d3c8b85d8a13038a16bd104cff1ea6e/_pytest/runner.py#L255))

I think that the easiest workaround would be to change how the "report" is constructed using `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook. It could be as simple as this:

```
from _pytest.runner import pytest_runtest_makereport as _makereport


def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    report = _makereport(item, call)
    report.keywords = dict(item.keywords)
    return report
```

Then in `pytest_runtest_logreport`, under `report.keyword['JIRA']` you will find [`MarkInfo`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/mark.html#_pytest.mark.MarkInfo) object

Comment: Bingo!!, Thats what I was looking for, Actually I had done the same thing for `TESTID` longtime back but some how I forgot that I have forgot this step for `JIRA`